# Type error Haskell, what's wrong?

Tags: haskell, hugs

I'm using hugs to compile a simple Haskell function calculating the number of permutations. I would like it to return an Integer, but I need to operate on floats.
I've tried to calculate the answer as a Float and then truncate it, but for some reason it's not working out.

This is the Function:

```
choose :: Float -> Float -> Integer
 choose n r = truncate (chooseF (n r))
    where
        chooseF::Float->Float->Float
        chooseF n r | n==r = 1
                        | otherwise =  n / (n-r) * chooseF(n-1) r
```

This is the Error (Line 35 is the second line of the function):

```
ERROR "/homes/mb4110/SimpleMath":35 - Type error in application
*** Expression     : n r
*** Term           : n
*** Type           : Float
*** Does not match : a -> b
```

It's probably something obvious that I'm missing but I've been at this for a good while and can't think of the solution.

Comment: Another bug due to what I call "Caskell". Haskell is not C... Don't use f(n), use f n. Also, use ghci.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chooseF` takes two arguments, but because of the parenthesis `n r` is parsed as a single argument. Thus, remove the parenthesis around `n r` and it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, now it's working. On another note is (n r) a data structure?

Comment: No, (n r) is not a valid expression, if as in this case, both n and r are of type Float. It would be a valid expression if n was a function, because then it would be simply function application.

Comment: `(n r)` is syntactically valid, since it represents the application of `n` to `r`, but it is not semantically valid since `n` is not a function.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are passing `(n r)` to `chooseF`.  Hugs determines from this that the term `n` must be some function of type `a -> b`, into which you are passing `r`.  The result of this would then be partially applied into `chooseF`.

Presumably, you wanted to call `chooseF` with both `n` and `r` as parameters instead.  To fix this error, call `chooseF n r` instead.